# El Capitan startup screens

Tags: macos, login, startup

After installing El Capitan (Currently on 10.11.3), the screen starts with a login prompt, which then displays a progress bar. At about 30%, the screen goes gray, then a faster progress bar completes the process.

I have read several answers and it seems to be related to Filevault.

I did have a GPU problem (MBP early 2011) which I resolved by entering a script available online, where I did modify the boot process disabling the discrete graphics and after that the boot started to display this additional progress bar; since then the motherboard was replaced (Thanks, Apple!), then I deleted all those extra features yet the startup screens remained.

Is there a way to have just one progress bar for the whole process?

I find that greyscreen somewhat annoying.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can fix this issue.

- Reset NVRAM
- Try starting up in Safe Mode
- Press and hold the power button for a few seconds until your computer turn off, then release the power button.

Source: [Apple Toolbox](http://appletoolbox.com/2015/10/mac-os-x-el-capitan-will-not-start-up-after-update-fix/)

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(